# null pointer exception while converting dataframe to list inside udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am reading 2 different **.csv** files which has only column as below:

```
    val dF1 = sqlContext.read.csv("some.csv").select($"ID")
    val dF2 = sqlContext.read.csv("other.csv").select($"PID")
```

trying to search if dF2("PID") exists in dF1("ID"):

```
    val getIdUdf = udf((x:String)=>{dF1.collect().map(_(0)).toList.contains(x)})
    val dfFinal = dF2.withColumn("hasId", getIdUdf($"PID"))
```

This gives me null pointer exception.
but if I convert dF1 outside and use list in udf it works:

```
    val dF1 = sqlContext.read.csv("some.csv").select($"ID").collect().map(_(0)).toList
    val getIdUdf = udf((x:String)=>{dF1.contains(x)})
    val dfFinal = dF2.withColumn("hasId", getIdUdf($"PID"))
```

I know I can use **join** to get this done but want to know what is the reason of null pointer exception here.

Thanks.

Comment: I think put a collect inside UDF is not a good manner and maybe is the source of the error. Think that function will be called too many times, so will perform a collect each time. Have you think about extract that collect outside and broadcast the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this question about [accessing dataframe inside the transformation of another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008296/creating-accessing-dataframe-inside-the-transformation-of-another-dataframe). This is exactly what you are doing with your UDF, and this is not possible in spark. Solution is either to use join, or collect outside of transformation and broadcast.