# Is there anyway in javaAPI to a Dataset<Row> to a map() and return a Dataset<Row>?

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with Java 8. I have an use-case as below,

```
Dataset<Row> ds = //a Dataset<Row> read from DB
```

I need to change do some manipulations based on the entries of another dataset
i.e.

```
List<String> codesList = Array.asList("code1","code2")
Dataset<Row> codes = sc.createDataSet(codesList , Encoders.bean(String.class))
```

I need process all code in parallel. To do the same I'm trying as below:

```
 Dataset<Row> ds_res =  codes.map( x_cod ->   //map throwing an error
        calcFunction(sparkSession, filePath, ds ,x_cod );
    }).reduce(new Function2<Dataset<Row> df1,Dataset<Row> df2) => df1.union(df2))

 ds_res .write().path(filePath).mode("append").save();

    public static Dataset<Row> calcFunction(sparkSession, filePath, ds ,x_cod ){
         //some complex calculation based on x_cod 

        return ds_res ; // return ds_res  for further processing
    }
```

How to make this work in parallel on the cluster?

Comment: You can't use `map` on a dataframe and use another dataframe inside. Do you need to map over `codes`? Couldn't you use `codesList ` instead (it should still be done in parallel)?

Comment: As long as you create and use a dataframe inside the `map` of another dataframe it won't work. You can read a bit more here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008296/creating-accessing-dataframe-inside-the-transformation-of-another-dataframe You probably need to find another way to solve the problem that does not require nesting the dataframes like this. Maybe you can use a list inside the function?

Comment: Currently your `calcFunction` returns a dataframe, correct? You are using `.reduce(new Function2<Dataset<Row> df1,Dataset<Row> df2) => df1.union(df2))` so you expect a list of dataframes as a result of using `map` on a single dataframe. So it looks like you takes a single dataframe, use `map` to get multiple dataframes. The only way to do this is to have nested dataframes which is not allowed. Maybe you can update it again to make it clearer? :)

Comment: I didn't have time to check during the weekend, but it looks like you got some answer there. :)

Comment: You should be able to do that, get an array with all datasets and the reduce with `union`. In this case you don't need an empty dataset to append to. (The alternative is to have a loop and append to a dataset, in this case you want to start with an empty dataset and add to that.)

Comment: In scala, you can just do: `val result = for( toDate <- dates){...}` with `res` on the last line inside the for-loop. This will give you the list.

Comment: Correct. `res` is what you want to put into the array. Since you have a for loop you will get a list of all `res`, this will automatically be returned as a list when using scala. See the second code block under "Returning values from a for-loop" here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-for-loops-foreach-how-to-translated-by-compiler/

Answer (score 2):

Encoding List to a Dataset is more feasible option that encoding. If you are planning to use a bean class you can encode it to that type of `Dataset<T>`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ParallelizeArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SparkSession sparkSess = Constant.getSparkSess();
        List<String> codesList = Arrays.asList("code1", "code2");
        final Dataset<String> dataFrame = sparkSess.createDataset(codesList, Encoders.STRING());
        dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).csv("src/main/resources/paraArray");
    }
}
```

or use

```
final Encoder<Dataset> bean = Encoders.bean(Dataset.class);
Dataset<Row> ds_res = codes.map((MapFunction<String, Dataset>) x_cod -> calcFunction(sparkSess, filePath, ds ,x_cod),bean)
                .reduce((ReduceFunction<Dataset>) (df1, df2) -> df1.union(df2));



    public static Dataset<Row> calcFunction(SparkSession sparkSession, String filePath, Dataset<Row> ds ,String x_cod ){
        Dataset<Row> ds_res = null;//some complex calculation based on x_cod
        return ds_res ; // return ds_res  for further processing
    }
```

Comment: this is the new way running a map reduce job in Spark 2. No need for write mapper and reducers all the time. All data sets are now streams in Spark 2.x  Spark engine will take care of the rest.

Comment: @BdEngineer Updated the ans to solve your compilation error but I would still suggest to use latest Spark APIs.

Comment: It is the return type of calcFunction function Encoders cant be created for Generics e.g. Dataset<Row> hence MapFunction and ReduceFunction were implemented using raw Dataset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212331/discussion-between-quicksilver-and-bdengineer).