# Operating in parallel on a Spark Dataframe Rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Environment: Scala,spark,structured streaming,kafka

i have a DF coming from a kafka stream with the following schema

**DF:**

```
BATCH ID: 0
+-----------------------+-----+---------+------+
|                  value|topic|partition|offset|
+-----------------------+-----+---------+------+
|{"big and nested json"}|  A  |        0|     0|
|{"big and nested json"}|  B  |        0|     0|
+-----------------------+-----+---------+------+
```

i want to process each row in parallel by using spark, and i manage to split them to my executors using

```
DF.repartition(Number).foreach(row=> processRow(row))
```

i need to extract the value from the value column into its own dataframe to process it.
Im having difficulties working with the Dataframe generic Row object..

is there a way to turn the single row in each executor to its very own Dataframe (using a fixed schema?)  and write in a fixed location?
Is there a better approach to solve my problem?

**EDIT + Clarification:**

The DF im receiving is coming as a Batch using a  `forEachBatch` function of the writeStream functionality that exists since `spark2.4`

Currently splitting the DF into ROWS makes it that the rows will be split equally into all my executors, i would like to turn a single GenericRow object into a DataFrame so i can process using a function i made

for example i would send the row to the function

```scala
processRow(row:row)
```

take the value and the topic and turn it back into a single-lined DF

```
+-----------------------+-----+
|                  value|topic|
+-----------------------+-----+
|{"big and nested json"}|  A  |
+-----------------------+-----+
```

for further processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are consuming multiple kafka data at a time.

First you need to prepare `schema` for all kafka topics, here for example I have used two different JSON in value column.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("""{"name":"Srinivas"}""","A"),("""{"age":20}""","B")).toDF("value","topic")
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------------------+-----+
|value              |topic|
+-------------------+-----+
|{"name":"Srinivas"}|A    |
|{"age":20}         |B    |
+-------------------+-----+
```

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
```

**Schema for topic A**

```
scala> val topicASchema = DataType.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""").asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

**Schema for topic B**

```
scala> val topicBSchema = DataType.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"age","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""").asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

**Combining topic & its schema.**

```
scala> val topicSchema = Seq(("A",topicASchema),("B",topicBSchema)) // Adding Topic & Its Schema.
```

**Processing DataFrame**

```
scala> topicSchema
.par
.map(d => df.filter($"topic" === d._1).withColumn("value",from_json($"value",d._2)))
.foreach(_.show(false)) // Using .par & filtering dataframe based on topic & then applying schema to value column.
+----------+-----+
|value     |topic|
+----------+-----+
|[Srinivas]|A    |
+----------+-----+

+-----+-----+
|value|topic|
+-----+-----+
|[20] |B    |
+-----+-----+
```

**Writing to hdfs**

```
scala> topicSchema
.par
.map(d => df.filter($"topic" === d._1).withColumn("value",from_json($"value",d._2)).write.format("json").save(s"/tmp/kafka_data/${d._1}"))
```

**Final Data stored in hdfs**

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "tree /tmp/kafka_data".!
/tmp/kafka_data
├── A
│   ├── part-00000-1e854106-49de-44b3-ab18-6c98a126c8ca-c000.json
│   └── _SUCCESS
└── B
    ├── part-00000-1bd51ad7-cfb6-4187-a374-4e2d4ce9cc50-c000.json
    └── _SUCCESS

2 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: i did not mention this earlier, the DF im using is in ForeachBatch  under writeStream 
so this exact soultion does not fit, i have added more details to the question.

Comment: can you explain reason why it will not fit for your solution ?

Comment: first, i made a mistake while trying your code, my bad, it works.
however it doesn't fit because i want to separate the rows into different dataframes because inside the json is the data that indicates where i will write them.
your solution separates them but they are in the same df, i want to separate them and send them to a function as separate dataframes!

Comment: may be you can use filter to split data & then pass that to your function.

Comment: Also above solution is doing filter based on ```topic``` column .. it will split the data into multiple dataframes then applying function individual dataframe.

Comment: i will give it a shot and update, regardless it does seem im hovering over the problem set here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008296/creating-accessing-dataframe-inside-the-transformation-of-another-dataframe
so im not very optimistic..

Comment: Yes, Inside DataFrame it is not possible.. Thats why I am extracting DataFrame using filter then applying functions on each DFs.

Comment: what if i have partitions on each topic and i need to separate the partition and/or offset as well?

Comment: i manged to separate them with nice function, tomorrow i will run this in my production environment and update if i succeed

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's better suited to use `.map` instead of `.foreach`. The reason is that the `map` returns a new dataset while `foreach` just a function and doesn't return anything.

One other thing that can help you is to parse the schema located in JSON.

I had a similar requirement recently.
My JSON object has a "similar" schema for both topic `A` and `B`. If that is not the case for you, you might need to create multiple `dataframes` in the solution below by grouping them by topic.

```
val sanitiseJson: String => String = value => value
  .replace("\\\"", "\"")
  .replace("\\\\", "\\")
  .replace("\n", "")
  .replace("\"{", "{")
  .replace("}\"", "}")

val parsed = df.toJSON
  .map(sanitiseJson)
```

This will give you something like:

```
{
    "value": { ... },
    "topic": "A"
}
```

Then you can pass that into a new `read` function:

```
var dfWithSchema = spark.read.json(parsed)
```

At this point you would access the value in the nested JSON:

```
dfWithSchema.select($"value.propertyInJson")
```

There are some optimizations you can do when it comes to `sanitiseJson` if needed.

Comment: this doesnt exactly solve my problem, to turn my json value into a DF i use
```from_json``` , what i need basiclly is to turn a Row object  back into a DF

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding what you want to do. Row object is by its definition part of the Dataframe.